# How to get and set lightning attributes

Tags: lightning-aura-components, design-attributes

I want to get and set 'disabled' and 'value' attributes of this lightning component:

```
<lightning:select aura:id="myId" name="select" label="Valore" required="true" onchange="{!c.tipoChanged}" value="{!v.caseItem.RRT_IRM_Meter__c}">
<aura:iteration items="{!v.listaSelect}" var="option"> 
    <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!option}" label="{!option}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

How can I do that without using {!v.mapping_attributes} in my cmp page?

I'm trying this solution but does not work:

```
tipoChanged : function(component, event) {
var src = event.getSource();
var tipo = src.get("v.value");
if(tipo=='Orario'){
  console.log('Orario');
}  }
```

Comment: You need to declare an `<aura:attribute name="myAttr"....>` tag in your component. Once you have that you will be able to use the `component.get("v.myAttr");` and `component.set("v.myAttr", "New Value");` methods. Have you gone through the Lightning Component Trailhead Modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do this using

```
component.find("myId").set("v.disabled", true); //or false
component.find("myId").set("v.value", anyValue);
```

[Working with Attribute Values in JavaScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_attr_values.htm)

Comment: And how to get the nested value? In the same way does not work: component.find("myId").get("v.value");

Comment: @Noomak as you want the select option value so this will also work `component.get("v.caseItem.RRT_IRM_Meter__c");`

Answer (score 0):

*You can set by finding Component using  **aura:id**  [Click how to Find Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_find_by_id.htm)*  and [Click How to Set Values to component attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_attr_values.htm)

**Example as per your code**

**Controller**

```
tipoChanged : function(component, event) {
    var src = event.getSource(),
        tipo = src.get("v.value");
    if(tipo == 'Orario ') {
       component.find("myId").set("v.disabled",true); // set value true or false
    }
    component.find("myId").set("v.value",tipo); 
}
```

Comment: Please do not add just code, but rather use *words* to explain what needs to be done and why. Code dump answers often end up in the Low Quality review queue, as this one did.